# Update other properties when OnPropertyChanged was triggered

Tags: c#, .net, model

I checked other links here but I can't really get the right answer. I have xaml which consists of two textboxes. The first is hours while the next is minutes. Whenever I change the value of hours in textbox, minutes should reset to 0. How can I do it with `OnPropertyChange`?

```
public class Variable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Variable()
    {
        this.hours = "1";
        this.minutes = "2";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string hours;
    private string minutes;

    public string Hours
    {
        get { return this.hours.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (this.hours != value)
            { 
                this.hours = value;
                this.minutes = "0";
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Hours");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Minutes { get { return this.minutes; } }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName ));
    }
}
```

Comment: do `this.OnPropertyChanged("Minutes")` after setting minutes to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `Minutes` textbox is read-only then you should have a setter for that property:

```
public string Minutes
{
    get => this.minutes; 
    set
    {
        if (this.minutes != value)
        {
            this.minutes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this setter in the `Hours` setter to notify UI of the change:

```
if (this.hours != value)
{ 
    this.hours = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged();
    this.Minutes = "0";
}
```

Instead if `Minutes` is correctly a read-only property then you have two options: make its setter `private` (and use it as above) or manually call `OnPropertyChanged()` to notify UI of the change:

```
if (this.hours != value)
{ 
    this.hours = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged();

    this.minutes = "0";
    this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Minutes));
}
```

I'm strongly against the second option because it adds unwanted complexity, I don't want to manually notify changes unless absolutely needed.

---

All these said you may improve few more things in your code.

`OnPropertyChanged()` has a parameter with `[CallerMemberName]` attribute then you do not need to specify the property name (if it's invoked from within that property). When you have to (see second example) then use `nameof(PropertyName)` instead of `"PropertyName"` because it'll be changed automatically when you rename your property.

I don't have a *big picture* of your code but if `Hours` and `Minutes` are integer property then you should have `int` instead of `string`. If input is wrong you'd better to inform user as soon as possible. Also you should validate values:

```
if (value < 0 || value >= 60)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
```

Not in this case but generally when you have a property where the backing field is there only because you do not have a setter then you can use:

```
public string Minutes { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply call the `OnPropertyChanged` invoker again with the name `Minutes`

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Minutes));
```

Or you can add a private setter to the minutes property that invokes it there.
So you'll have something like this:

```
public class Variable : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Variable()
    {
        this.hours = "1";
        this.minutes = "2";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string hours;
    private string minutes;

    public string Hours
    {
        get { return this.hours.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            if (this.hours != value)
            { 
                this.hours = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

                this.Minutes = "0";                    
            }
        }
    }

    public string Minutes 
    { 
        get { return this.minutes; }
        private set
        {
            if(this.minutes == value)
                return;

            this.minutes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged()
        }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName ));
    }
}
```

By the way, The `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in the invoker means that if you don't pass the parameter any value, it'll take the name of whoever called it. In case of a property, it'll be the name of that property, so you don't have to write it.